# calculating y_pred in least square regression (R)?

Tags: r, regression, equation, least-squares

I'm having trouble calculating the y_pred in the least square regression. The idea is something like:

```
mydata <- read.csv("G:\\sample.csv",header=T)
x<-rep(mydata$wavelength,each=119)
y<-c(mydata$v1,....mydata$v119)
lm(y~x)
```

A sample data can be download at: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86_a8ltyoL3Y3BhU2xFVVo5dnM/view?usp=sharing

In the file, variable "Wavelength" is x, where for each x, there are multiple y measured at different times, as indicated by variables V1 to V119.

I'm not sure the y(multiple)~x(one) regression...
Can someone help out to calculate y_pred in this case?

Big thanks!

Comment: Either use `predict.lm` (but read the help page carefully) or grab the slope and intercept values from your result and hand-calculate new x,y pairs.

Comment: Start by reading the help page for `lm` with the command `help('lm')`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is just

```
mydata <- read.csv("G:\\sample.csv",header=T)
lm(Wavelength ~ ., data = mydata)
```

This does a regression of `Wavelength` against all of the other columns in your dataframe.

In your call to

```
x<-rep(mydata$wavelength,each=119)
```

`x` ends up null. You need to capitalize `Wavelength`.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was how to calculate predicted values from an `lm` model.

Comment: I used predict() to get the predicted value